# How do I configure xdmx on my Ubuntu machines?

Tags: ubuntu, xdmx

I've got a desktop machine and a laptop, both running Ubuntu 10.04.
I want to be able to use the laptop screen as a secondary monitor for the desktop, like [MaxiVista](http://www.maxivista.com/) allows you to do with Windows (their home page has a nice animation showing what I'd like to accomplish).

Searching the web turned up that this is possible on Linux using software called xdmx.
I installed the xdmx and xdmx-tools packages from the repositories, but have been unsuccessful in getting it to work.

I've read somewhere that I should have both X servers listening on TCP, but I don't know how I'd do that. I've looked through the [man pages](http://dmx.sourceforge.net/Xdmx.html) for xdmx but that didn't really get me very far.

Does anyone have experience with getting xdmx up and running?

Comment: do you mean xbmc (X-Box Media Center) or is there a program xdmc?

Comment: I mean the Distributed Multihead X Project :)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but asking this on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ may be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with xdmx, but the `gdmsetup` GUI is the easiest way I know to get the X server listening on TCP.  Check the security tab.

Comment: Unfortunately, GDM has been rewritten and Ubuntu 10.04 has the new version. gdmsetup has been stripped down and no longer has the functionality you describe. There isn't a suitable GUI replacement yet as far as I can tell.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's been a long time since I personally did it.   I believe all the manual configuration you need is at http://library.gnome.org/admin/gdm/2.30/configuration.html.en#xdmcpsection

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/gdm/gdm.conf - where it says `DisallowTCP=true` you want `DisallowTCP=false`. 
You may also need to comment out `-nolisten tcp` in /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc. This should get the X server listening on TCP.

Check if it is with `telnet <IP adress> 6000`. It should successfully connect but not show any output (or perhaps a daemon message?).

What other troubles are you running into? What error messages do you get when you try to make it run?

Comment: OK but how would you use the X server as the second screen on the other machine?